# search into loaded file

Tags: java, spring, string

Generaly I have pplication Window, where I can select file to load. Next I want to make few operations on loaded data.
I have problem with "searching" in loaded file.
This is how I am loading text file.

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
```

I would like to change in my loaded file lines with "Y" sign. 
If there is "Y =  2" I would like to have "Y = -2". Problem is that "-" is not always  in the same place.

I have tried to replace that Strings useing:

```
if(content.contains("Y") && content.contains("-")) {
                    content = content.replace("Y =     -","Y =      " );
                    content = content.replace("Y =    -","Y =     " );
                    content = content.replace("Y =   -","Y =    " );
                    content = content.replace("Y =  -","Y =   " );
                    content = content.replace("Y = -","Y =  " );                                    
                }
```

But it works only in one way- when I have only "-" in file.
File looks like this:

```
P[1]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  4007.202  mm,  Y = -2356.597  mm,  Z = -1130.101  mm,
    W =   165.198 deg,  P =    30.150 deg,  R =   -47.243 deg
};
P[2]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  3249.045  mm,  Y = 3095.068  mm,   Z =   642.444  mm,
    W =    63.553 deg,  P =    -5.645 deg,  R =  -130.279 deg
};     
P[5]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1830.140  mm,  Y =  -879.342  mm,  Z =   577.282  mm,
    W =   102.636 deg,  P =     3.797 deg,  R =  -178.377 deg
};
P[6]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1805.656  mm,  Y =   788.587  mm,  Z =   570.342  mm,
    W =    90.000 deg,  P =     0.000 deg,  R =  -179.762 deg
};
    P[7]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1808.476  mm,  Y =  -723.783  mm,  Z =   571.716  mm,
    W =    90.000 deg,  P =     -.000 deg,  R =  -179.762 deg
};
P[8]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1808.988  mm,  Y =   776.000  mm,  Z =   571.501  mm,
    W =    90.000 deg,  P =     0.000 deg,  R =   180.000 deg
};
P[9]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1808.984  mm,  Y =    -1.200  mm,  Z =   571.509  mm,
    W =    90.000 deg,  P =     0.000 deg,  R =   180.000 deg
};
P[10]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  2283.352  mm,  Y =     8.892  mm,  Z =   613.716  mm,
    W =    89.709 deg,  P =    -2.407 deg,  R =  -166.205 deg
};
P[11]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  3124.694  mm,  Y =     -.544  mm,  Z =   501.109  mm,
    W =    69.303 deg,  P =    16.675 deg,  R =  -136.733 deg
};
P[12]{
   GP1:
    UF : 2, UT : 7,     CONFIG : 'N U T, 0, 0, 0',
    X =  1884.062  mm,  Y =      .584  mm,  Z =   609.822  mm,
    W =    96.232 deg,  P =     8.892 deg,  R =  -166.064 deg
};
```

Comment: consider accepting an answer if it helped you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to negate the value of all occurrences of `Y`.
For example:

- `Y = -2356.597` should become `Y = 2356.597`
- `Y = 3095.068` should become `Y = -3095.068`

If so, you could apply the following pattern replacement:

- Replace `Y =` followed by spaces with itself and a `-` appended
- Replace `Y =` followed by spaces and `--` with itself and `--` removed

Like this:

```
input.replaceAll("(Y = +)", "$1-").replaceAll("(Y = +)--", "$1"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is what I want to get ;) 
So at first I am adding to every  "Y" sign "-" and in second replaceAll() I am replacing "--" with " "removing it :D

Comment: @astatyzm Exactly!

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` only applies the change to the first occurrence of the given regex it finds.

I would recommend using the `replaceAll()` method to replace all the occurrences in your String.

Also you can modify your regex so you need only one call of the method no matter how many blanks are between the 'Y' the '=' and the '-' like this:

```
content.replaceAll("Y( )*=( )*-","Y = ");
```

Comment: Thank a lot. replaceAll() is that method which I was looking for ;)